# Applet printing fine on Windows, but not on Mac

Tags: java, macos, applet, jeditorpane

We built an mvc in .net for receipts.  We wrote a small applet that takes in a url to our view and prints the receipt generated at that url to the users default printer.

There is one specific receipt that doesn't use our mvc because it isn't tied to a sale and is merely a tip slip for a service.  The main difference between this receipt is that the page that displays the preview of it (along with the button to print it) is the same page that the applet will use to print it.  So, the applet essentially takes the url of the preview but with an extra param in the query string telling it to not render anything other than just the tip slip content.

This all works perfectly on Windows on any browser.  However, when we switch to a Mac, the tip slip only prints about 15% of the time, the rest of the time it just prints a tiny sliver of blankness.  It's as if the applet is getting no content from the url, even though when I link to that exact url through the browser I get the tip slip content.

I'm thinking this may be a timing issue.  Perhaps the applet is not waiting until the tip slip is rendered.

This is the applet's print method code:

```
public void printDocument(final String url, final boolean ccInfo,
        final boolean printDialog)
{
         AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>() {
         @Override
    public Object run()
    {
      try
    {
      new ParserDelegator();

      JEditorPane jEditorPane = new JEditorPane();
      jEditorPane.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit() {
        @Override
        public ViewFactory getViewFactory()
            {
            return new HTMLFactory() {
            @Override
            public View create(Element elem)
            {
              View view = super.create(elem);
              if (view instanceof ImageView)
            {
              ((ImageView) view)
              .setLoadsSynchronously(true);
            }
              return view;
            }
        };
    }
  });

  jEditorPane.setPage(url);
  JeditorRendererer docRenderer = new JeditorRendererer();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
  System.out.println("IO Exception");
  e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
  return null;
}
```

});
}

As you can see, in order to get our barcode to not display as a broken image icon I overwrote the method for creating an ImageView so that it loads it synchronously.  Is there something similar for the rest of the html content?  A receipt will all be text in html and an image tag at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to delay printing until all events are processed by the applet using [java.awt.EventQueue#invokeLater](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable))? You can even try to fire a thread that waits for 1 sec and then fires printing via the java.awt.EventQueue#invokeLater.

I woudn't rule out buggy applet printing on the Mac. Frankly, I have never seen people print via applets.

If you see you are spending too much time debugging applet on the Mac I would consider one of the two:

1. Layout the receipt in HTML, possibly with the use of generated PNG images and have the user print them manually; there is even way to invoke printing function from the HTML page using JavaScript.
2. Generate PDF file and let them download it -- everybody has some way of printing PDF files.

Comment: Yeah, we already have an alternative method of printing receipts on all platforms that does work.  This was just supposed to be an easier instant print option for our users.  Aside from this one thing on Macs it works.  I also already had a time delay in there that was there for the image loading problem I had before.  Even with it at 7 seconds, tip slips just didn't work on a mac.  I'm all out of ideas on why it's not working.

Comment: Of course you know that you can initiate the "Print" function from the HTML page, like Google Maps does? Sounds easy enough to me...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I just said.  We already have a method that allows the user to print.  The problem is I don't want the print dialog to pop open.  I want them to be able to click a button and instantly print to their default printer.  This is the whole point of our applet.  It works aside from these tip slips on macs.